# Locate an item in a multidimensional array by using a single index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this multidimensional array:

```
points= [['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6'] ]
```

and i have this array of points needed for a check in the above array;

```
new_points = [ 'a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

[image]

So `a` goes to `1` (0,0) , `b` to `2` (0,1) etc so points becomes;

```
points= [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'] ]
```

the multi-dimension array will always be **3 by 3**, **4 by 4** etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use two `.map()` and in nested function get index of relevant item of `new_points` based on map index.

```js
var points= [['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6']];
var new_points = [ 'a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

var newArr = points.map(function(item, i){
  return item.map(function(val, j){
    return new_points[(item.length*i)+j];
  });
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: With all due respect ... you do promote questions with zero effort shown with your answer.

Comment: @Akrion You're right, users first should try and if can't ask question. But i answered to this question because it is simple and has short solution

Answer (score 0):

If points is 2 dimensional but the nested array can be of variable length then you can reduce points using a counter to help get the item from new_points:

```js
const points = [[1], [2, 3]];
const new_points = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const createNewPoints = (points, new_points) =>
  points.reduce(
    ([result, counter], items) => [
      result.concat([
        items.map((_, i) => new_points[i + counter]),
      ]),
      counter + items.length,
    ],
    [[], 0],
  )[0];
console.log(createNewPoints(points, new_points));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could shift each element of `new_points` by mapping the original array structure.

```js
var points = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']],
    new_points = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

points = points.map(a => a.map(Array.prototype.shift, new_points));

console.log(points);
```